# maximun transfer hops count is exceeded on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I had to move some messages from a topic to a queue, and then forward to another queue to change the messages expiry date. I did that some times and I ended up reaching maximum hop count which is 4 as it is written in [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues.md).

How can I change the MaxTransferHopCountExceeded value or is there any trick to move a million messages from the dead-letter queue to an active one so I can consume them?

I have a premium subscription on azure.

Answer (score 2):

Maximum number of hops is 4 and cannot be modified.

> How can I change the MaxTransferHopCountExceeded value or is there any trick to move a million messages from the dead-letter queue to an active one so I can consume them?

Auto-forwarding messages from a dead-letter queue would count as a single hop and shouldn't be an issue. If you have auto-forwarding from a dead-letter queue to subsequent queues several times, you'll need to ensure not to exceed the maximum number of hops. I had a [post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/auto-forwarding) a while ago that also covered message reprocessing with auto-forwarding from dead-letter queue(s).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sean, my problem though is that I manually forward 4 times the messages in order to update the expiry-date. I know this was stupid but seems there is a problem with Microsoft and I couldn't increase the expiry-date of the messages. Now I want to move them to a topic, with 2 subscriptions, and Service bus shows the error "maximum hop count reached". As a solution, I am building a new app to read the messages from the dead-letter queue and then publish them to a topic. I am asking if there is another more clever solution. I wish I had read your blog earlier!

Comment: @Emanonk, have you tried to write a simple consumer on the DLQ to receive and re-send the messages with desired expiry date?

Comment: @Emanonk, you can auto-forward from any DLQ to another queue/topic w/o the need to create any custom code. This is done by specifying the entity to forward to. I can recommend either [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases) or [QueueExplorer](https://www.cogin.com/).

Comment: @AresOu this is what I ended up doing. I couldn't find any other solution. Thank you!